# Python Pandas Barcode Generation

Tags: python, pandas, barcode

I have a spreadsheet that I am trying to create Code128 or Code39 barcodes in a column. When trying to create the barcodes from the excel doc I am running into different issues depending on the type of barcode I am trying to create.

Example Input

```
0 row1.rack1
1 row1.rack1
2 row1.rack1
3 row1.rack2
4 row1.rack3
5 row5.rack8
6 row2.rack1
```

Code Example

```
from barcode import Code39
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

def cleanup ():
   df1 = read_file
   df8 = df1['Shelf'].str[:-7]
   df11 = df8.str.split('.').str[0]
   df12 = df8.str.split('.').str[1]
   df13 = df11.str.split('row').str[1]
   df14 = df12.str.split('rack|case|table|display|endcap|bin|dispenser').str[1]
   df15 = df13 + '.' + df14
   df16 = Code39(df8.str, writer = ImageWriter())
   df = pd.Dataframe({'row/rack': df15, 'barcode': df16})
   df9 = df.sort_values(['row/rack', 'Shelf'], kind=str, ascending = (True, False))
   df9.loc[df9['Barcode'].duplicated(keep='first'), 'Barcode'] = ''
```

Error

```
KeyError: 'ROW1.RACK1'
```

If I change it to Code128 I get

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

If I use code128 and remove ".str" after df8 I get

```
raise IllegalCharacterError(
barcode.errors.IllegalCharacterError: The following characters are not valid for Code 128: row1.rack1, row1.rack1, row1.rack1
```

Any help provided will be very appreciated! I'm still very new to programming and self taught

UPDATE:

I tried changing

```
df16 = Code39(df8.str, writer = ImageWriter())
```

to

```
    df16 = str(df8)
    df17 = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
    df18 = df17(df16, writer = ImageWriter())
```

I didn't get any terminal errors from this but when opening the excel doc I got the following output

```
"0          row1.rack1
1          row1.rack1
2          row1.rack1
3          row1.rack1
4          row1.rack1
            ...      
2993    row48.rack100
2994    row19.rack101
2995    row19.rack101
2996    row13.rack100
2997    row13.rack100
Name: Shelf, Length: 2998, dtype: object"
```

Maybe putting them back into excel isn't the right option? Is there a way to get these all to save as separate files?

Comment: I tried saving it as file to see what happens and it just combined them all into one massive barcode.... I assume I need to iterate over the document in someway but can't find how to do it